Create history and log for Power Automate cloud flows
How to create history and log for Power Automate cloud flows
and add all the workflow logs in a SharePoint list?

Create a SharePoint list and create item whenever there is a failure/success (or whenever you want to log the history). Configure the Run after of actions to achieve this.
To populate the SharePoint list, use workflow() function to obtain necessary information such as executionid, name, start time, end time, etc. You can also use internal flow variables to obtain information like duration, inputs, triggerOutputs, response or value of a certain variable during the flow execution.
Here's an overview of the execution and implementation of workflow() function.
